# intellij import not working, scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have a scala worksheet whereby im trying to import a method from another object. In intellij it does not seem to work, whereas if I import the method in sbt console it does. I'm new to Scala, and to languages on the JVM, so I apologize for not being able to define this problem better. I have attached two screenshots which show the behaviourI'm describing. Running the worksheet results in the following errors:

[image]

whereas everything works in the sbt console:
[image]

I have tried invalidating and restarting the caches as suggested in other posts but this has not worked.

EDIT: foob file as requested

```
package objsets

/**
  * Created by michael on 6/26/16.
  */
object foob {
 def g(x: Int): Int = 10*x
}
```

Comment: That should be working. Would you mind posting the foob file?

Comment: I can only reproduce it occasionally. Seems to be something in Intellij. It goes away be renaming the object though.